# How run t-sql commands on Azure SQL databases using Ansible

Tags: sql-server, azure, ansible, paas

We need to run a series of T-SQL statements (to create database objects and inert data) on an Azure SQL databases (not Managed Instance database flavour) using Ansible, hosted on an Azure Linux VM.

We successfully tested that we can and run the sql commands from the Linux VM having installed odbc drivers. However, we get connection timeout errors when we try to run the sql scripts using Ansible, from the same Linux VM.

Ansible uses ssh (port 22) to connect to remote hosts. SQL server communicates on Port 1433.

Is what we are trying to do supported by Ansible?
If supported, please could someone point us to how this can be achieved.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**By default, Ansible runs tasks synchronously, holding the connection to the remote node open until the action is completed.** This means within a playbook, each task blocks the next task by default, meaning subsequent tasks will not run until the current task completes. This behavior can create challenges. **For example, a task may take longer to complete than the SSH session allows for, causing a timeout.** Or you may want a long-running process to execute in the background while you perform other tasks concurrently. Asynchronous mode lets you control how long-running tasks execute.

**Async: async is used to explicitly set the timeout you wish to apply to this task. Rather than relying on the connection method timeout, we can have a custom timeout for a particular task.** The async tasks will run until they either complete, fail, or timeout according to their async value.

Poll: poll is a value for which the playbook will stick on the task until it either completes, fails, or times out. For long running asynchronous tasks, it’s good to set poll=0 so that Ansible can immediately jump to the next task after starting the current one without waiting for the result.

Retries: the number of times you want to retry to check the status of the job until it gets timeout or declared as failed. For example, if you have set retries=20, it will try to check job status after every 10 seconds (if poll=10) 20 times. In short, it will wait for the task to complete for 200 seconds in total.

Here's an example.

```
--- 
- 
  hosts: dbhost
  name: "Import MySQL database"
  tasks: 
    - 
      async: 2100
      name: "Start database import"
      poll: 0
      register: import_db
      shell: "mysql {{ MYSQL_DATABASE }} < /backups/database_dump.sql"​
```

You can also refer ansible official docs for [Asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html).